# For-each loop, larger than 20 into another array

Tags: php, loops

I'm stuck on this exercise that I can't seem to get for the life of me.

```
$numbers2 = [21, 5, 4, 6, 76, 2, 18, 85, 55, 1];

foreach ($numbers2 as &$value) {
    $largeNumbers[] = $value > 20;
}
```

That's the code I have so far. What I am trying to do here is use a for-each loop to add all the numbers that are larger than 20 into another Array, which I have named $largeNumbers. The code I have inserted above seems to be printing out true and false values, which is not what I was going for. I'd really appreciate it someone could tell me what I'm possibly doing wrong or even show me a better way. **I have to use a for-each loop.**

Comment: `$largeNumbers = array_filter($numbers2, function($value) { return $value > 20; } );`

Comment: Take a look here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each item, you are checking if it's larger than 20, which results in a boolean value (it either is or is not), and you then store this value to the result array. Instead, you could use an `if` statement` to only take the elements that answer the condition:

```
foreach ($numbers2 as &$value) {
    if ($value > 20) {
        $largeNumbers[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$nums = [21, 5, 4, 6, 76, 2, 18, 85, 55, 1];

$less_than_or_equal_to_20 = [];    
foreach($nums as $v)
    if($v <= 20)
        $less_than_or_equal_to_20[] = $v;

$out = array_diff($nums, $less_than_or_equal_to_20);
var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array ( 0 => 21, 4 => 76, 7 => 85, 8 => 55, )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$nums = [21, 5, 4, 6, 76, 2, 18, 85, 55, 1];

foreach([$nums] as $v)
    $out = array_filter($v, function($v) {
        return $v > 20; 
    });

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array ( 0 => 21, 4 => 76, 7 => 85, 8 => 55, )
```

Comment: you can lose the `foreach()` line and replace `$v,` with `$nums,` - https://eval.in/872421

Comment: @WeeZel yes but they 'have to' use foreach.

Comment: ahh, missed that :-) coding tests - who needs them?!